# Firefox doesn't display text on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox

I was successful in displaying text on webpage but in firefox, it does not display the text at all. If i see the page source, it has text in there. but why doesn't it display? In Chrome and  IE, it works fine.

Edit:
When i used firebug, it looks like the content is behind the screen. I just guess. What you experts say on this?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<div>
<table id="Table2" width="150%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
    class="main_content">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td align="left" style="height: auto">
            <br />
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#006699"
                Font-Names="Verdana"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:32px"> </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td align="center">
            <div class="reusableBlueBox" style="width: 500px;height:auto;">
                <div class="reusableBlueTop">
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="reusableBlueContent">
                    <table id="Content" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" class="createAccountTable">
                      <%-- <tr><td align="left" valign="top"><h2 align="center">WELCOME TO OUR SITE...!</h2></td></tr>--%>

                        <tr id="trwelcome" runat="server">
                           <td>
                               <div style="text-align: center; margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
                                   <span style="color: #00669f; font-size:large; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold" > Welcome</span> <br>
                                   <span style="color: #00669f; font-size:small; font-family:Arial" > Please look over this welcome page to 
                                   familiarize yourself with your account. </span>
                               </div>
                           </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr id="trhelp" runat="server" visible = "false">
                            <td> 
                                <div style="text-align: center; margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
                                   <span style="color: #00669f; font-size:large; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold" > Help</span> <br>
                               </div>
                            </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr style="height:10px">
                       <td> </td> </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <td id="tdWelcomeContent" runat="server" valign="top" class="listStyleNone">
                           </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="trthankyou" runat="server">
                        <td align="left">
                        <strong><span style="color: rgb(0,102,153); font-size: medium">Thanks for joining.</span></strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                    </table>
                      <table width="200">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 109px; height: auto">
                        </td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; height: auto" align="center">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEnterMyAccount" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/enter_my_account.gif"
                            OnClick="imgbtnEnterMyAccount_Click" Width="185px" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; height: auto">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                </div>
                <div class="reusableBlueBottom">
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <br />
          <%--  <table width="200">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 109px; height: 37px">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnhelp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/help2.gif" OnClick="btnhelp_Click" Visible="False" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; height: 37px" align="center">
                        &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEnterMyAccount" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/enter_my_account.gif"
                            OnClick="imgbtnEnterMyAccount_Click" Width="185px" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; height: 37px">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 109px; height: 47px">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; height: 47px">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; height: 47px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>--%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We would need a link to the page or the page source code to be able to look at this problem - what you have included in your question is not enough to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: You could take a look at the error console in FF, or run some good old fashioned alerts to check your variables/element values/css/etc, but without any code as they said above it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

As other said you should post the full HTML to find the problem (and not the ASP.NET page as you did)

However, it seems that one of your tr tag is missing the td tag inside:

```
<tr style="height:32px"> </tr>
```

This is not complaiant HTML and I would check if this is causing the problem to Firefox.
Also look at the DTD in the header of the page.